# jquery ajax calls form authentication issue

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, iis-7

I am making jquery ajax calls to server after each 10 seconds from a page. Now when a user makes normal request (no ajax call) to server (if he stays idle for 2 minutes) I want the user to become log out. I have already made a form authentication cookie with timeout 2 minutes but the issue is that automatic jquery ajax calls(after each 10 seconds) are not making the user unauthenticated. How can I handle this case.

Comment: clear the interval for the AJAX requests after 2 minutes ?

Comment: but won't the expiration has already extended in my case since sliding expiration is true in my case and as the ajax call is maded with in those 2 minutes the expiration is extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the interval and remove the authentication cookie after 2 minutes :

```
var intervalID=window.setInterval(yourajaxfunction,10000);

window.setTimeout(  
    function() {  
        clearInterval(intervalID);   // cancel the ajax requests
        clearCookie(); // remove the authentication cookie locally
    },  
    120000  // 2 minutes timeout
);
```

I'm guessing that on the server side there is a check for the authentication cookie - if its not found then the user is forced to re-authenticate.

Comment: Yes that should be done automatically by form authentication module. But in this case ajax calls are made continiously and since cookies are set along with ajax calls form authentication module will treat the user as if he has visited the site and hence it will slide the expiration further and the more requests are sent to server the more further expiration will become.

Comment: @RockySingh perhaps my answer was not detailed enough - the idea is that the ajax calls would be stopped (im guessing you start the ajax calls using th `setInterval` method ?)... using the `clearTimeout()` method after 2 minutes (from page load) and the cookies cleared ... this means no more communication and the next time the user connects to request a page - there is no cookie - forcing re-authentication

Comment: But there can be other ajax calls on the page say send message or some chat application on that page. User might be sending messages from that. I just want that my continuous ajax calls should not extend form authentication timeout

Comment: @RockySingh but then the user is active and surely should be forced to re-login after 2 minutes ? just clear all of the automated ajax calls this way - if the user performs an action should the 2 minutes not be reset ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a validation function @ server side .
every ajax request call this validation first and if valid execute your script normally . if not valid you can clear cookies .

Comment: I didn't get you. Do you have some sample or some link?